# When I'm blocked by a Facebook user, is their profile hidden when I log out too?

Tags: facebook

It would appear as if when a user blocks me, I cannot see their profile when logged out either. Is this true?

Answer (score 1):

No, its not true. You can see *public* profile of that person who has blocked you when you are not login to your account.

Comment: Weird. I wonder why it says "Sorry, this page isn't available. The link you followed may be broken, or the page may have been removed."

Comment: Just clean your browser and try.

Comment: I've tried a separate computer, separate browser and separate IP. Almost like it needs some sort of referrer to work.